# Converting files between Altium Designer and Circuit Studio board layout file

Tags: pcb, altium

I am using Altium Designer 17 in my institute, but in my laptop I have Circuit Studio 1.4. Schematic file made in Altium Designer can be opened in Circuit Studio.

Is it possible to open layout file in Circuit Studio, generated by Altium Designer? Is there any conversion software available to convert the files between the two?

Comment: on the circuit maker forum there is this (https://circuitmaker.com/forum/posts/213465/1), but I have not been able to make this work in 16.0, 17.0, 17.1 or 18 releases of Altium. Give it a shot, other people seem to have success with it. Since you are at an institute (I am assuming a school) you may not be able to install the importer yourself, so try asking a staff member or assistant if needed.

Comment: Yes, I am at University, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

To open an Altium Designer PCB document in CircuitStudio do the following:

1. In Altium Designer Save your PCB as a PCB 5.0 binary file. Do this by going 
   to file > save as > from the pulldown menu choose PCB5.0 Binary
2. In CircuitStudio go to file > import and choose the PCB5.0 binary file you 
   just created.

that should work.

If you're using Altium Designer 18 (which I know you are not currently using) you would just need to go to file > export and choose CircuitStudio (in Altium Designer).

Comment: What version of Altium are you using? I'm on 17.1 and I don't see this as an export option. Did you have to first "add exporter" in the same "File > Export" menu?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I was using version 18 not 17. Give this new method a chance, if you're still having trouble let me know.

Comment: Good addition, confirmed that it works with Altium 17.1 and CircuitStudio 1.4 (Not sure why you got a downvote).